# HP LoadRunner Java recording

Tags: java, performance, testing, loadrunner

I have a jnlp file. When I run it, it connects to specific ip/port and downloads a java application which allows me to connect to NEP server through username/password

I tried to know the directory of this java file and it shows me that it is in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\javaws.exe

but task manger shows me it is in

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\j2plauncher.exe

I want to record logging in in HP LoadRunner and I have chose java over HTTP recording. When i choose javaws or j2plauncher and puting -wait (directory of jnlp file) then press start recording i got the same issue. Nothing recorded.

What could be wrong and how i can fix it ?

Comment: i figured out the problem now i am facing another one .. in recording options in java over HTTP protocol .. i choose the javaws.exe first then i write javaws  -system D:\nep.jnlp .. when i start recording i got message .. unable to start application ..

 InvalidArgumentException[ Invalid arguments supplied: {D:\nep.jnlp, javaws }]
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
?????

Comment: How do you know, architecturally, that your Java application communicates across HTTP?

Comment: i know that it using RMI protocol

Comment: Then why are you Choosing Java over HTTP when you know the application leverages a different interface, RM/I? This is a very confusing decision.